# How to show json data in Recyclerview?

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

How can i add json data in my datalist? Right now recycleview shows the data comes from getdata() method.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

    rv = (RecyclerView)layout.findViewById(R.id.listViewCountry);

    getJSON(JSON_URL);

   vivzAdapter = new VivzAdapter(getActivity(),getData());

    //  vivzAdapter  = new VivzAdapter(getActivity(),getData());

    rv.setAdapter(vivzAdapter);

    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    /*lv = (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.listViewCountry);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,country);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);*/


    return layout;
}

public  static List<Information>  getData()
{
    List<Information> data = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] icon ={   R.drawable.photo,R.drawable.photo,R.drawable.photo,R.drawable.photo,
                    R.drawable.photo,R.drawable.photo,R.drawable.photo,R.drawable.photo,
                    R.drawable.photo,R.drawable.photo,R.drawable.photo,R.drawable.photo,
                    R.drawable.photo,R.drawable.photo,R.drawable.photo,R.drawable.photo};
    String[] title = {"Hi","Hi","Hi","Hi","Hi","Hi","Hi","Hi","Hi","Hi","11","12","13","14","15","16"};

    for(int i =0; i<title.length;i++)
    {
        Information current = new Information();
        current.iconId = icon[i];
        current.title = title[i];

        data.add(current);
    }



    return data;
}

//json class

private void getJSON(String url) {

    class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //loading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Please Wait...",null,true,true);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String uri = params[0];

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(uri);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                String json;
                while((json = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
                    sb.append(json+"\n");

                }

                return sb.toString().trim();

            }catch(Exception e){
                return null;
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            //loading.dismiss();

            //vivzAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //textViewJSON.setText(s);

            json_string = s;

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



        }
    }

    GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
    gj.execute(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Change the get data function to parse the json data. for example if the json is like this

```
  {
   "obj": 
   [
     {
      "name": "name1",
      "url": "http://www.someweb.com/path"
     },
     {
       "name": "name1",
       "url": "http://www.someweb.com/path"
     },
     {
       "name": "name1",
       "url": "http://www.someweb.com/path"
     }
    ]
   }
```

loop through the json to create objects(Information in your case) and add it to the list

```
public  static List<Information>  getData(JSONObject json) 
{ 
  List<Information> data = new ArrayList<>(); 
  JSONArray ary = json.getJSONArray("obj");    

  for(int i =0; i<ary.length;i++) 
  { 
    Information current = new Information(); 
    JSONObject j = leaders.JSONObject(i);
    current.name = j.getString("name");
    current.web  = j.getString("url");
    data.add(current); 
  } 
    return data; 
}
```

in your `onPostExecute` create the adapter, set adapter and set layout manager for your recycler view

```
    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject o) {
        super.onPostExecute(o);
        vivzAdapter = new VivzAdapter(getActivity(),getData(o));//create the adapter
        rv.setAdapter(vivzAdapter); // set adapter for recycler view
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(yourActivity.this));// set layout manager for recycler view
    }
```